# importing igor pro files (ibt) to matlab

Tags: matlab, import, export, igor

Anyone know how to import ibt files directly into matlab? I want to use matlab to analyze my electrophysiological data. The igor pro website only discusses exporting graphics, though it can import from matlab.

I have figured out how to get individual waves into matlab but it requires going through all the waves individually - instead of just importing the entire recording.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42679-igor-pro-file-format--ibw--to-matlab-variable) submission from the file Exchange? Otherwise does the solution you are referring to consist in exporting as delimited text file?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that file --- I'll take a closer look to check, but I have ibt files, not ibw. The solution that I've found (that is roundabout and takes longner) involves putting all the waves in a table and then saving the table as a .csv or .txt file.

Comment: Is this an answer or should it rather be a comment to the question?

Comment: @Schorsch Well the File Exchange submission would provide a solution to the original question so in this sense it would be an answer yes doesn't it? If not I can remove my answer.